# Converting a list to dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

I've gone through many questions but couldn't find what i was looking for.
I have a list something like this:
    `[2, 3, 5, 7, 11]`
and I want to convert it into a dictionary in the format:
i.e. the values of the list should be keys and each associated value should be zero.
    `{2:0 , 3:0 , 5:0 , 7:0 , 11:0}`

Comment: `{x:0 for x in a}` where `a` is your initial list

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A dict comprehension will do.

```
my_list = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11]
my_dict = {k: 0 for k in my_list}  # {2:0 , 3:0 , 5:0 , 7:0 , 11:0}
```

Even if you are not familiar at all with comprehensions you could still do an explicit `for`-loop:

```
my_dict = {}
for k in my_list:
    my_dict[k] = 0
```

Comment: or even `dict.fromkeys(my_list,0)`

Comment: There are many duplicate of this answer floating around Stack Overflow. If OP actually just google his problem it would link to at least 3.... Maybe try flagging it instead of promoting this behavior. But nevertheless it's an answer

Comment: Actually i didn't knew the exact term to search for. :p

Comment: @Ev.Kounis is the possible to change(i mean increase or decrease) the value associated with each key via a loop or something  (after initializing the dictionary)?

Comment: for a specific key or for all keys?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis
what i wanna do is to initialize the values to each key as 0.
After that i want to run a `for` loop in a list of numbers. If the same number is found as a value in the dictionary i want to increase it's key every time that  number is found. 
when i try to access the value,the above method produces an error "  'int'  object is not iterable" . 
Long story short: specific key

Comment: `for item in my_other_list: if item in my_dict: my_dict[item] += 1`

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
l =  [2, 3, 5, 7, 11]
d = {}

for item in l:
    d[item] = 0
```